# Develope 2D game on Android/iOS with libgdx requires a Mac?

Tags: android, ios, linux, macos, libgdx

Wanted to use `libgdx` to develop a 2D game on `Android` and `iOS`. As I was reading the requirements to develope it on eclipse, I read this:

> To additionally target iOS:
>
> **A Mac, iOS Development does not work on Windows/Linux thanks to Apple.**
>   The latest XCode, which you can get from the Mac OS X App Store for free
>   RoboVM, simply install the Eclipse plugin. Make sure to update the plugin frequently!

Is this true? Is there no way to additionally target iOS on Linux?

I know, it's just my opinion, but thats a pretty sad move by Apple...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need the Mac for Xcode and the signing of the IPA.

I believe you can create an unsigned IPA that would run on jail broken devices, but I am unsure whether a Mac is still required.